# How to get localized MapLocation in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I'm using a simple method that returns map location for me, but I would like to get that address in english only.

```
public static async Task<MapLocation> ResolveLocationForGeopoint(Geopoint geopoint)
{
    MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(geopoint);

    if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success)
    {
        if (result.Locations.Count != 0)
            // Check if the result is really valid
            if (result.Locations[0].Address.Town != "")
                return result.Locations[0];
    }
    return null;
}
```

My problem is: When my windows language is russian it returns cirillic characters.

I have tried to override the application language:

```
ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en";
```

But it seems it doesn't works...

How could i get the localized string from this method?

Comment: Maybe the name of the city or the location is in Cyrillic characters, why do you want to change it?

Comment: Becouse I use the map in Hungary and there are no Cyrillic characters in any hungarian city name. :D It just display every name in the system language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn636928) method does not provide a mechanism to specify the language used in the returned address now. It always automatically uses the Windows display language. And in most cases, the [Street](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.services.maps.mapaddress.street) and [Town](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.services.maps.mapaddress.town) are localized to its local culture. For example, if you request a location in France, the street names are localized in French.

As a workaround, we can use [Bing Maps REST Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx) which provides REST APIs that can specify [Culture Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701709.aspx). For `FindLocationsAtAsync` method, we can use [Find a Location by Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx) like following:

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/47.64054,-122.12934?c=en-US&key=BingMapsKey
```

Also, you are welcome to submit a feature request on [**WPDev User Voice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform) to ask for this feature.